# Gender of Italian and foreign cities

Tags: gender, proper-nouns

I heard from a friend of mine from north of Italy that "Vieux Lyon" (="old Lyon" in French) sounds weird to him, since "Vieux" implies that Lyon is a masculine noun, while according to him, all cities are feminine in Italian. Indeed, according to my Italian dictionary, even cities ending with -o (e.g. Berlino, Milano) are feminine. However, now I have a different friend from Sicily, who uses always the masculine form for foreign cities (e.g. "Vecchio Düsseldorf"). Now, I'm confused and would like to ask the following questions:

- Is there a general rule for cities? (If yes, the questions below are not probably not relevant anymore)
- Are there also masculine cities in Italy?
- Which gender would you use for relatively minor foreign cities (e.g. Düsseldorf) and how does it sound to you if the opposite gender is used?

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find an answer to your question in the book *Italiano* by Luca Serianni (chapter III, 10-12):

> In particolare, tendono a collocarsi nel genere femminile: 
>
> I. [...]
> II. I nomi di città, isole, regioni, stati, continenti: *la Roma dei papi*, *la sabauda Torino*; *la Sardegna*, *la Sicilia*, *le Eolie*, *la
> Campania*, *l'Emilia-Romagna*; *l'Austria*,
> *la Finlandia*; *l’Africa*, *l'Asia*, *l'Europa*. 
> In antico il genere dei nomi di città era perlopiù determinato dalla desinenza: «Palermo fu fabbricato», «bella Venezia», «bel mi' Firenze» (ROHLFS 1966-1969: 380a); alcuni esempi letterari di maschile in *-o*: «in un Milano, bisogna dirla, c'è ancor del timor di Dio» (Manzoni, *I Promessi Sposi*, XVI 48); «quel Milano birbone ch'era tutto pieno di lei» (De Marchi, *Demetrio Pianelli*, 333); «abbiamo in faccia Urbino / ventoso» (Pascoli, *L'aquilone*, 22-23). Oggi fra i più comuni
> nomi di città è invece maschile solo *Il Cairo* (anche se s'ode ancora, nella lingua
> parlata, «il mio Torino», «Milano è sempre il più bello»; e se i toponimi in *-o* possono presentare alterati scherzosi al maschile: «Palermo, Palermino sei più bello di Torino» Ginzburg, *Lessico famigliare*, 31).

My translation:

> In particular, they tend to be placed in the female gender:
>
> I. [...]
> II. The names of cities, islands, regions, states,
> continents: *la Roma dei papi*, *la sabauda Torino*; *la Sardegna*, *la Sicilia*, *le Eolie*, *la
> Campania*, *l'Emilia-Romagna*; *l'Austria*,
> *la Finlandia*; *l’Africa*, *l'Asia*, *l'Europa*. 
> In ancient times the gender of city names was mostly determined by the ending: «Palermo fu fabbricato», «bella Venezia», «bel mi' Firenze» (ROHLFS 1966-1969: 380a); some literary examples of masculine in *-o*: «in un Milano, bisogna dirla, c'è ancor del timor di Dio» (Manzoni, *I Promessi Sposi*, XVI 48); «quel Milano birbone ch'era tutto pieno di lei» (De Marchi, *Demetrio Pianelli*, 333); «abbiamo in faccia Urbino / ventoso» (Pascoli, *L'aquilone*, 22-23). Today, among the most common names of cities, only *Il Cairo* is masculine (although we still hear, in the spoken language, «il mio Torino», «Milano è sempre il più bello»; and if toponyms end in *-o* they can present joking alterations in masculine: «Palermo, Palermino sei più bello di Torino» Ginzburg, *Lessico famigliare*, 31).